# How to enabled pdo mysql in Centos 5.8

Tags: php, centos, centos5

I have a VPS with Centos 5.8

In phpinfo displays: './configure' '--disable-fileinfo' **'--disable-pdo'** '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pic' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'

I've tried this:

http://www.host1free.com/forum/vps-technical-support/7248-tutoria-centos-apache-webserver-mysql-php-eaccelerator-apc.html

And aparently it installed php-pdo

```
# rpm -qa |grep php
php-5.3.13-1.el5.remi
php-xml-5.3.13-1.el5.remi
php-common-5.3.13-1.el5.remi
php-cli-5.3.13-1.el5.remi
php-pdo-5.3.13-1.el5.remi
php-xmlrpc-5.3.13-1.el5.remi
php-mcrypt-5.3.13-1.el5.remi
```

But I've restarted apache and it still says in my phpinfo: **'--disable-pdo'**

Should I rebuild php? Do I need to do some other step?

Answer (score 1):

Installing additional extensions does not change the options PHP was compiled with. Verify that the pdo_mysql extension is installed via `php -m` or `phpinfo()`.

Comment: This is the result # php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
imap
json
libxml
mysql
openssl
pcre
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
SQLite
sqlite3
standard
timezonedb
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib